# Novice. Ways to use geoJson file in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

JS/Leaflet novice so interested in good coding examples/approaches.  Have a `geoJSON` file with a couple thousand objects.  I want to set line attributes (e.g. color) based on a value in the `JSON` file (i.e. features. InActive which can either be 0 or -1).  I also want to create a separate group layer for each so I can give the use layer display control.

One approach I could take is to loop through the `JSON` file and add each object to a group layer (based on the InActive value) and then style the group layer.

Are there other approaches?

Comment: Continuing to read.  Appears I could use the .onEachfeature geoJson API method.  Am I correct in assuming I don't need to add an array index to reference the feature data?  The other is to use an i++ loop.  In both approaches, the main action would be to add the polygon to one of the two layerFeatures (to give user layer control).  Another question, can I style a layerFeature?

Comment: More testing.  In the i++ loop approach, what API should be used?  geoJSON would be called for each feature which seems inappropriate even if it works.  Is it better to shift to a polygon API?  This seems to be one of the key reasons to possibly pick the geoJson.onEachfeature approach.(?)

Comment: It appears I can isolate the geoJson feature either way (onEachFeature and loop through array).  How do I add the feature to the layerGroup?